# How to specify onMarkerclick() for different types of markers in android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

On google map i am placing different colors of markers for different purposes, here i want different functionality for onMarkerclick() for each marker( ex:all green color markers).How to make condition for this.here is my code to create one set of markers

```
@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng touchlocation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(touchlocation)
            .title("Event")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
}
```

Here another type of marker

```
// adding marker
        user_marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(USER_LOCATION)
                .title("User")
                .snippet("User registered Location:" + loc)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE)));
```

For nearby places i am using another type of marker

here how i implemented onMarkerClick()

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // googleMap.clear();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "USER MARKER",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    showDialog(DIALOG_LOGIN);

    return true;
}
```

here i want different functionality for each type of marker ,how to write a condition for that.help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

If all your `Marker`s have a value you can distinguish on (e.g. title), you may do this:

```
String title = marker.getTitle();
if ("User".equals(title)) {
    // show dialog
} else if ("Event".equals(title)) {
    // do thing for events
} else {
    // do thing for nearby places
}
```

Snippet can be used for this, but you have to take care of creating info window `View` if you don't want to show snippets like `"USER"`, `"EVENT"` or `"NEARBY_PLACE"` constants.

A more general way could be storing all your `Marker`s in `Set`s (or `Map`s if you want to assign additional value to every `Marker`):

```
private Set<Marker> events;
private Set<Marker> nearbyPlaces;
```

and later checking if clicked `Marker` is in one of these sets:

```
if (user_marker.equals(marker)) {
    // show dialog
} else if (events.contains(marker)) {
    // do thing for events
} else if (nearbyPlaces.contains(marker)) {
    // do thing for nearby places
} else {
    // something is wrong, better call police (assuming there are only 3 kinds of markers)
}
```

Last but not least, you can use [Android Maps Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/) to remove ugly `if` statements.

Create one `OnMarkerClickListener` for each `Marker` type, e.g.:

```
private OnMarkerClickListener userMarkerClickListener = new OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        // show dialog
        return true;
    }
};

private OnMarkerClickListener eventMarkerClickListener = new OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        // do thing for events
        return false;
    }
};
```

When creating `Marker` of a given type, assign click listener:

```
user_marker.setData(userMarkerClickListener);
```

In your global `OnMarkerClickListener`, which is added to `GoogleMap` object call:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    OnMarkerClickListener listener = (OnMarkerClickListener) marker.getData();
    return listener.onMarkerClick(marker);
}
```

If you have only 3 kinds of `Marker`s, I would go for the second option, because it is simple and robust. If more than 5 or likely to change in the future, object-oriented code created using third option will be easier to maintain IMHO.

Comment: How do you create markers? I can only see the ability to add a marker via MarkerOptions, e.g. `googleMaps.addMarker(new MarkerOptions(...))`

Comment: Scratch that. addMarker returns the marker so the set option works well.

Comment: Would prefer switch cases instead of if else, especially for the first one

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like...

```
   String Title = marker.getTitle();
          Log.e("I am in onMarkerClick" , Title);
    if(Title.equals("Pick Me")){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),filterAddress,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("I am in onMarkerClick", Title);
    }else if (Title.equals("Drop ME")){
        Log.e("I am in onMarkerClick" , Title);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),DropoffAdress,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

//Title is the markeroptions.Title("Your specified Title");

Answer (score 0):

I create a listener for each marker. This way I will have a more organized and maintainable code.

```
private GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener portoAlegreMarkerClickListener = new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome to Porto Alegre", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
};
```

Then I created the marker and in the following instruction I passed the private listener as a tag. This worked. If someone knows how to pass this listening in a better way then share it with us.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {    
    markerPortoAlegre = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(portoAlegre)
            .title("Porto Alegre"));
    markerPortoAlegre.setTag(portoAlegreMarkerClickListener);
}
```

Finally I create an instance to get my global listener using `getTag()`. I think this way is a way to modularize the listening of the markers separately, unlike when we use `googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)` and a single overridden method onMarkerClick for all markers.

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener listener = (GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener) marker.getTag();
    //I used listener!=null to avoid an exception
    return listener != null && listener.onMarkerClick(marker);
}
```

*This way you would have to modify onMapReady and add global listeners as many times as markers need. The last method I wrote will always be the same.*